# Extracting specific feature class from dataset in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, feature-class, iterator

I would like to be able to run a model that iterates through datasets and at one point extracts just a single point feature from within the dataset and save it in a different geodatabase.  The problem I run into is that the feature class to feature class tool will not recognize my inline string for the path of the feature class.  It wants me to point a feature class within the model to the feature class to feature class tool.  Is there a way to "extract" a single feature class from a dataset and then use it as the input for the next tool in the chain within model builder?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the select tool?

Comment: Yay!!! Thankyou @Hornbydd!  Can't believe I hadn't tried this yet.  I used the Select Data (ModelBuilder only) tool.  It is now working.  At least this part...

Comment: Perhaps you can write up a brief answer on this?  It may also help to clean up the feature/feature class/feature dataset terminology in the question.